# android maps disable movement

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw with my finger an overlay on google maps.
I already accomplished that the line is drawn.. 
But the map moves also with my finger and so i cant draw very well, because i just can draw a small circle around my finger when the map also moves...

How can i disable the movement (dragging) of the map and be still able to draw and display an overlay with my finger?

My current Code looks like this:

```
public class OverlayMap extends Overlay {
    private List<MapGeoLine> geoLines = new ArrayList<MapGeoLine>();
    private List<GeoPoint> geoPoints;
    private boolean isTouched = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent, MapView mapView) {

        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ 
            geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
            geoPoints.add(mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)motionEvent.getX(),(int)motionEvent.getY()));
            isTouched = true;
        }

        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            if(isTouched){
                geoPoints.add(mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)motionEvent.getX(),(int)motionEvent.getY()));
            }
        }

        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if(isTouched){
                geoPoints.add(mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)motionEvent.getX(),(int)motionEvent.getY()));
            }           
            isTouched = false;
        }   

        return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent, mapView);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {  

        if(geoPoints != null && geoPoints.size() > 1 && !isTouched){
            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2); 
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 

            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

            Point from = new Point();   
            Point to = new Point();
            Path p = new Path();

            projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(0), from);            

            for(int i = 1; i < geoPoints.size(); i++){          
                projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(i), to);
                p.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
                p.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
                from.set(to.x, to.y);               
            }  

            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }

}
```

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return true from `onTouchEvent()` when you process the `MotionEvent` and don't want it to be processed by anyone else.

Otherwise you return false, and the event will be processed by the `MapView` resulting in a map movement.

Regards.

Comment: Its not working in my case can you please help me. [see my question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android/20916931#20916931)