# How to draw free hand polygon in Google map V2 in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, draw, polygon

I want to draw a `Free Hand Polygon on the Map in Google Map V2`.

This task was possible with `Overlay` Map V1 but Google Map has removed that class from V2. (Per this [Google Map V2 has Remove Overlay Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526482/android-maps-api-v2-where-are-the-overlays)).

[Good Example for Google Map V1 to draw free style polygon.](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-google-maps-android)

> In Map V2, we can draw a polygon programmatically with the help of [Google Official  Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes) but what should a user do? I have found [Unclear answer for Map V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798419/freeform-drawing-with-android-maps-v2)

I started with simple Google Map & draw polygon to do this programmatically & it is working properly but now I am looking for how a user can draw? I don't want to draw based on the marker on the polygon.

```
// Instantiates a new Polygon object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
              .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0),
                   new LatLng(37.45, -122.0),
                   new LatLng(37.45, -122.2),
                   new LatLng(37.35, -122.2),
                   new LatLng(37.35, -122.0));

// Get back the mutable Polygon
Polygon polygon = myMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

I have done lots of Research and Development on this topic but didn't get a perfect way to implement such a thing in Map V2.

**Some Questions**

- How to draw freestyle polygon in Map V2 (as we can do with Map V1)?
- Is there any trick or alternative to achieve this? If yes how?
- Can we get a touch event on the map & draw polygon?
- Is it feasible in Map V2?
- Is it possible with a touch event which returns array of lat-long?
- How can I get Lat-long based on screen coordinates on `setOnDragListener`?

Each new version has something extra compared to the older one so I am expecting that I can achieve the same thing in Map v2 also.

I am not asking to give me some sample code or post your code, just some proper direction & documentation.

I have provided all documents and evidence I found during the Research and Development.

Comment: Did you require to draw a polygon - line on Google Map v2?

Comment: yes,that is my exact question

Comment: @chintankhetiya: Hey, I was trying to draw a free hand polygon on map v1 but I couldn't find any help on your said link(above).

Comment: @chintankhetiya HI. Are you there??

Answer (score 87, accepted):

After spending a whole day in Rnd and testing some alternatives I have found a solution. Actually I have found two alternatives for the same issue but I would like to suggest the using of **Alternative 2** because that is really very easy compared to **Alternative 1**.

Actually I have found **Alternative 1** with the help of [TheLittleNaruto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944896/thelittlenaruto) , [AndroidHacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967597/androidhacker) and some other developers & **Alternative 2** with the help of [Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066573/khan) so thanks to all.

**Alternative 1**

> How to Draw Free style polygon in Map V2 (as we can do with Map V1) ? Is it feasible in Map V2 ?

Yes, that is feasible but you can't get directly `OnTouch()` & `OnDraw()` on the map. So we must have to think some other way to achieve this.

> Is there any trick or alternative way to achieve this thing , if yes how ?

Yes, Google Map V2 doesn't support `OnTouch()` or `OnDraw()` on a Map using `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` so we have to plan for a custom Fragment.

> Is it possible to return array of lat-long with touch event ?

Yes, if we create any custom map fragment and use it we can get that **Touch** or **Drag** event over the map.

> How can I get Lat-long base on screen coordinates on setOnDragListener ?

`setOnDragListener` will return screen coordinates **(x,y)**. Now for that, there are some techniques to convert **(x,y)** to **LatLng** and they include [Projection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection) along with [Point](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) & [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng).

```
customMapFragment.setOnDragListener(new MapWrapperLayout.OnDragListener() {@Override
    public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.i("ON_DRAG", "X:" + String.valueOf(motionEvent.getX()));
        Log.i("ON_DRAG", "Y:" + String.valueOf(motionEvent.getY()));

        float x = motionEvent.getX(); // get screen x position or coordinate 
        float y = motionEvent.getY();  // get screen y position or coordinate 

        int x_co = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.round(x))); // casting float to int 
        int y_co = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.round(y))); // casting float to int 

        projection = mMap.getProjection(); // Will convert your x,y to LatLng
        Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);// accept int x,y value
        LatLng latLng = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points); // convert x,y to LatLng
        latitude = latLng.latitude; // your latitude 
        longitude = latLng.longitude; // your longitude 

        Log.i("ON_DRAG", "lat:" + latitude);
        Log.i("ON_DRAG", "long:" + longitude);

        // Handle motion event:
    }
});
```

> How does it work ?

As I have already mentioned before, we have to create a **custom root view** and using that we can get **Touch** or **Drag** Events over the map.

Step 1: We Create `MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment` and we will use that as our .xml file

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="pkg_name.MySupportMapFragment" />
```

Step 2: Create a `MapWrapperLayout extends FrameLayout` so that we can set a **Touch or Drag listener** inside and embed its view with map view. So, we need one Interface which we will use in Root_Map.java

**MySupportMapFragment.Java**

```
public class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    public View mOriginalContentView;
    public MapWrapperLayout mMapWrapperLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        mMapWrapperLayout = new MapWrapperLayout(getActivity());
        mMapWrapperLayout.addView(mOriginalContentView);
        return mMapWrapperLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mOriginalContentView;
    }

    public void setOnDragListener(MapWrapperLayout.OnDragListener onDragListener) {
        mMapWrapperLayout.setOnDragListener(onDragListener);
    }
}
```

**MapWrapperLayout.java**

```
    public class MapWrapperLayout extends FrameLayout {
     private OnDragListener mOnDragListener;

     public MapWrapperLayout(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }

     public interface OnDragListener {
         public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
         if (mOnDragListener != null) {
             mOnDragListener.onDrag(ev);
         }
         return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
     }

     public void setOnDragListener(OnDragListener mOnDragListener) {
         this.mOnDragListener = mOnDragListener;
     }

 }
```

**Root_Map.Java**

```
public class Root_Map extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static boolean mMapIsTouched = false;
    MySupportMapFragment customMapFragment;
    Projection projection;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.root_map);
        MySupportMapFragment customMapFragment = ((MySupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mMap = customMapFragment.getMap();

        customMapFragment.setOnDragListener(new MapWrapperLayout.OnDragListener() {               @Override
            public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Log.i("ON_DRAG", "X:" + String.valueOf(motionEvent.getX()));
                Log.i("ON_DRAG", "Y:" + String.valueOf(motionEvent.getY()));

                float x = motionEvent.getX();
                float y = motionEvent.getY();

                int x_co = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.round(x)));
                int y_co = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.round(y)));

                projection = mMap.getProjection();
                Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);
                LatLng latLng = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points);
                latitude = latLng.latitude;
                longitude = latLng.longitude;

                Log.i("ON_DRAG", "lat:" + latitude);
                Log.i("ON_DRAG", "long:" + longitude);

                // Handle motion event:
            }
        });
    }}
```

Reference [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223155/creating-ondraglistener-for-google-map-v2-fragment) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429877/how-to-get-screen-coordinates-from-marker-in-google-maps-v2-android)

Up to here I am able to get **LatLong** based on **X,Y screen coordinates**. Now I just have to store it in **Array**. That array will be used for drawing on the map and finally it will look like a free shape polygon.

> [image]

I hope this will definitely help you.

## Update:

**Alternative 2**

As we know, **Frame layout** is a transparent layout so I have achieved this using Frame Layout.
In this case, there is no need to create a custom fragment. I have just used **Frame Layout** as root layout. So basically I will get **Touch Events** in the root layout and that will return screen coordinates, as we got in custom fragment previously.

Now, I have created a Button inside the "Free Draw". So when you click on that you can move your fingers on the map and draw a free hand polygon and that will disable your map being movable on screen. When you re-click the same button, the  screen goes in ideal mode.

**root_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fram_map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Free Draw" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Root_Map.java**

```
FrameLayout fram_map = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fram_map);
Button btn_draw_State = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_draw_State);
Boolean Is_MAP_Moveable = false; // to detect map is movable
```

// Button will change Map movable state

```
btn_draw_State.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Is_MAP_Moveable = !Is_MAP_Moveable;
    }
});
```

Touch Click of Frame Layout and with the help of the do some task

```
fram_map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {     @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        int x_co = Math.round(x);
        int y_co = Math.round(y);

        projection = mMap.getProjection();
        Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);

        LatLng latLng = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points);
        latitude = latLng.latitude;

        longitude = latLng.longitude;

        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // finger touches the screen
                val.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // finger moves on the screen
                val.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // finger leaves the screen
                Draw_Map();
                break;
        }

        return Is_MAP_Moveable;

    }
});
```

// Draw your map

```
public void Draw_Map() {
    rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.addAll(val);
    rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(7);
    rectOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
    polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
}
```

Yet, now you have to maintain your list while you draw, so you have to clear your previous list data.

Comment: @chintan ... Great work buddy and thanks for sharing this valuable info. +1 for that. :)

Comment: superb..Good question and Answer too

Comment: it never enters MotionEvent.ACTION_UP in fram_map.setOnTouchListener. why?

Comment: Great work! i liked your devotion towards **Do it yourself**. Really helpful. the only thing i can suggest is if `DrawMap()` is being called from `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` it will look more nice. 
Keep up the good work and your contribution in the community. Thanks

Comment: @Emilla are you returning `true` from `onTouch`?

Comment: Also you missed `break` for MOVE and DOWN!

Comment: @chintankhetiya Thanks for the DIY. I'm using the second example and it's working fine. The only problem I have here is that ACTION_UP is somehow working synonymously with ACTION_MOVE. i.e. Draw_Map() function is called each time I'm moving my finger. Can you please find out what's the problem here?

Comment: I modified the XML so the FrameLayout wraps around my maps fragment. However, it is never stepping into the onTouchListener. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Great Work!!!
I am using Alternative 1 but my problem is the MAP is movable. So how to hold the map for the time while the polygon is drawing?

Comment: Thank you so much that was really helpful.

Comment: I follow your tutorial but not able to create complete circle it get location from center point so circle is not displaying properly.

Comment: After Drawing, is there any api for implementation of searching in selected drawing area.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out .. I believe U are capable of showing Google Map v2

Check out "decodePoly" and "drawPath" method in AsyncTask

Main Imphasis in "drawPath" ..

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
    LatLng point = list.get(z);
    options.add(point);
}
line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Complete class for your reference ..

```
package com.example.androidhackergooglemap;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Polyline line;
    Context context;

    Location location;
    boolean check_provider_enabled = false;

    // Static LatLng
    LatLng startLatLng = new LatLng(30.707104, 76.690749);
    LatLng endLatLng = new LatLng(30.721419, 76.730017);

    public void onCreate(Bundle bd) {
        super.onCreate(bd);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = MainActivity.this;

        // GoogleMap myMap
        myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startLatLng));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        location = service.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
        // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabled) {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);*/
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable GPS servcies to use this app.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                String urlTopass = makeURL(startLatLng.latitude,
                    startLatLng.longitude, endLatLng.latitude,
                    endLatLng.longitude);
                new connectAsyncTask(urlTopass).execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // Now auto clicking the button
        // btntemp.performClick();
    }


    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String url;

        connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) {
            url = urlPass;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.hide();
            if (result != null) {
                drawPath(result);
            }
        }
    }

    public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat,
        double destlog) {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin="); // from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination="); // to
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
        return urlString.toString();
    }

    public class JSONParser {

        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {}

        public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                json = sb.toString();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return json;
        }
    }

    public void drawPath(String result) {
        if (line != null) {
            myMap.clear();
        }
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endLatLng).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(startLatLng).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        try {
            // Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List < LatLng > list = decodePoly(encodedString);

            PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
            for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
                LatLng point = list.get(z);
                options.add(point);
            }
            line = myMap.addPolyline(options);

            /*for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
                line = myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                                new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                        .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List < LatLng > decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List < LatLng > poly = new ArrayList < LatLng > ();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

**UPDATE**

check out this .. [Creating OnDragListener for Google Map v2 Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223155/creating-ondraglistener-for-google-map-v2-fragment)

Also check this one ..
[How to draw a shape on the map fragment by touching it using google map V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713310/how-to-draw-a-shape-on-the-map-fragment-by-touching-it-using-google-map-v2)

Some more reference .. [How to get screen coordinates from marker in google maps v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429877/how-to-get-screen-coordinates-from-marker-in-google-maps-v2-android)

Comment: nice strategy for making url "makeURL()" +1 for that.

Comment: that is static way to implement , i have already done this. I want to draw from user side and get that polygon `lat-long array`

Answer (score 2):

So we do have some solution for free hand draw on map v2.
Implement `GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener` in your map activity . It'll override onMarkerDrag function.

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

   //add the marker's latlng in a arraylist of LatLng and pass it to the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylistoflatlng.size(); i++) {
         myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(arraylistoflatlng)
        .width(5)
        .color(Color.RED));
    }
    }
```

you can pass some kind of hack for free hand like as soon as the user will touch the map, you'll have to detect that coordinates and pass it to the the onMarkerDrag . As you'll have to use the area's information for further process. For touch event you can implement `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener` and get the coordinates from it's parameter. 
Hope this will help :)

Comment: i don't want to draw using marker, i have already mention in my query. btw thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

this is google maps API V2 tutorial :

```
public class MapPane extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

        // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                .add(new LatLng(-33.866, 151.195))  // Sydney
                .add(new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431))  // Fiji
                .add(new LatLng(21.291, -157.821))  // Hawaii
                .add(new LatLng(37.423, -122.091))  // Mountain View
        );
    }
}
```

link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i did it yesterday night +1