# Is it possible to draw shapes on google maps with mouse and then view them on mobile device with Android v4?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to create some zones on the map with mouse and then view a map with those zones on my mobile device. I would like also detect if I'm within any of created zones. Is it possible? And ... what's important - is that free? I've heard about some restrictions for google geolocator, but I'm not sure if the same apply for such possibility if such is present.

I would be grateful for any hints.

cheers

Comment: I know how to draw a free hand polygon into map. Go to this question:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android)

Comment: Yes, but I would need to know the GPS coordinates of all edges of the shapes I would like to draw that's why I prefer to draw them with mouse and then check if I'm inside this shape or not. Hmmm.. I assume it's not possible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is possible. There's a page:
https://www.google.pl/maps/d/u/0/

that allows creating maps. After creating a new map I'm able to draw shapes with my mouse and export them to KML/KMZ formats afterwards. 
That is what I was looking for. I'm posting it here, so maybe I'll help someone looking for the same feature.