# Drawing on map by finger and get latlong

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-v2

my Question is how to draw any shape on map by finger and get latitude and longitude in Google map please help me its very difficult to me some answer i have found on stack overflow and another websites  but that's not working 
Thanks in Advance:-

Comment: What you try, post your code and that's not working...

Comment: i m trying to draw a  custom circle by finger on Google map and get latitude and longitude

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android.......but this not hep me

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar with HERE maps, full codes for it can be found from the [AreaSelector example at github](https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples/tree/master/AreaSelector)

The idea is really simple. You just have two draggable markers, one for moving the circle position in the map, and one for changing the radius, and when each one of them is moved, you just change the circle accordingly. So that idea could be a nice starting point for your custom circle drawer as well.

Comment: thanks for giving answer but this article only for Nokia and i want to it for Android..@Dr.Jukka

Comment: the point is the idea on how it works, its basically really easy to implement with any maps offering. But if you are looking for somebody to do the full implementation for you, then of course you can keep on looking. But if you ant to get it done and learn programming, then I would suggest you try out implementation as suggested.

Comment: HTTP://Stackoverflow.com/questions/23514568/marker-show-if-marker-inside-polygon-and-invisible-if-marker-outside-polygon-in".......Can you Suggest Any Answer This Questiobn

Comment: you might want to clarify what you are asking, as you can see the question was closed because people did not understand what it is that you were actually asking in there.

Comment: i was asking that how i get the lat-long point is inside/outside the polygon and i have a Array-List of lat-long from server @Dr.Jukka

Comment: My Question is how to find lat long inside the polygon or not i have 1000 markers in my database , when app started then all markers visible and when we draw shape and apply then only marker inside the polygon show ,,this is very important for me please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest that you figure out the problem you have with the suggested API there.