# Draw Heart Shape Polygon on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polygon

I am trying to create heart shape polygon on Google Map using current location. I am able to identify some LatLngs and tried to create heart shape but as expected curves are not showing.

How can I create exact heart shape polygon using current location?

Here is code which I am using to create heart shape.

```
private static final int FRONT = 0;
private static final int RIGHT = 90;
private static final int LEFT = 270;

private void drawHeartPolygon(LatLng currentLatLng) {
    LatLng destLatLang = GetDestinationPoint(currentLatLng, FRONT, 0.050F);
    frontAngleCalculation(currentLatLng, destLatLang, 0.050F);
}

private void frontAngleCalculation(LatLng latLng, LatLng destLatLang, float distance) {
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    LatLng centerLocation = GetDestinationPoint(latLng, FRONT, (distance + (distance/4)/2)/2);
    LatLng rightLocation = GetDestinationPoint(centerLocation, RIGHT, distance/2);
    LatLng leftLocation = GetDestinationPoint(centerLocation, LEFT, distance/2);
    LatLng centerLeftLocation = GetDestinationPoint(destLatLang, LEFT, distance/4);
    LatLng centerLeftTopLocation = GetDestinationPoint(centerLeftLocation, FRONT, (distance/4)/2);
    LatLng centerRightLocation = GetDestinationPoint(destLatLang, RIGHT, distance/4);
    LatLng centerRightTopLocation = GetDestinationPoint(centerRightLocation, FRONT, (distance/4)/2);
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),
            leftLocation,
            centerLeftTopLocation,
            new LatLng(destLatLang.latitude, destLatLang.longitude),
            centerRightTopLocation,
            rightLocation);
    Log.d(TAG, "Current Location : "+latLng);
  
    rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);

    // Get back the mutable Polygon
    Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.<PatternItem>asList(
            new Dot(), new Gap(20), new Dash(30), new Gap(20));
    polygon.setStrokePattern(pattern);
    polygon.setStrokeWidth(POLYGON_STROKE_WIDTH_PX);
    polygon.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);
   
}

public static LatLng GetDestinationPoint(LatLng startLoc, float bearing, float depth) {
    LatLng newLocation = null;

    double radius = 6371.0; // earth's mean radius in km
    double lat1 = Math.toRadians(startLoc.latitude);
    double lng1 = Math.toRadians(startLoc.longitude);
    double brng = Math.toRadians(bearing);
    double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(depth / radius) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(depth / radius) * Math.cos(brng));
    double lng2 = lng1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(depth / radius) * Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(depth / radius) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2));
    lng2 = (lng2 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;

    // normalize to -180...+180
    if (lat2 == 0 || lng2 == 0) {
        newLocation = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
    } else {
        newLocation = new LatLng(Math.toDegrees(lat2), Math.toDegrees(lng2));
    }

    return newLocation;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady");
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(22.0f);
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(17.0f);
    drawHeartPolygon(new LatLng(latitude,  longitude));


}
```

Here is screenshot which shows heart shape which I achieved but not as per expectation:

[image]

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20916931/8244632) help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you'll like this answer or not but this will work as your requirement and is easy as hell but different.

Just place a marker:

```
        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(13.014849, 80.224343);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("Name").snippet("snippet").flat(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker1)));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng1).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Here, marker1.png is an image created through photoshop which will provide the same result.
Result:
[image]
Marker1.png:
[image]

As you can see marker1 here is a whole image containing the marker + the heart but you can also create two markers on same `LatLng`: 1st is the red marker and 2nd is the Heart. Using this way, `infowindow` will open only on clicking the red marker instead of the provided result as you can disable the heart's `infowindow` or you can use heart's `infowindow` for some other info.

As I said earlier this solution is different and isn't similar to custom shaped polygon but is super easy to achieve.